# How to monitor Windows server Registry changes

Tags: windows, windows-registry, security

Hi i want tools or audit policy that can help me to track all changes made to windows server registry (include who done the change - what is the old value -what is new value -change type {delete -create - modify)

Your support is highly appreciated

Comment: I Just found few articles regarding monitore registry through WMI    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144468/tracking-changes-in-windows-registry

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSMonitorRegistryChange-d297cdf0

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65dc039e-3645-4a01-a8fa-7cb373aac36b/using-wmi-to-monitor-registry

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Security Log Event ID 4657](http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4657) will tell you when someone edits a registry key, so you can look for that in your Event Viewer.  The only caveat to this is that you have to turn on auditing first.  [See this to turn on auditing for both domain and workgroup environments.](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Auditing-changes-to-the-registry)

[This is also a link from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324739) supporting the method from techtarget.com.

Comment: i tried this one but the issue that it will create bulk of events and most of them was for querying key only i need something more specified like editing keys, removing, creating

Comment: You may have to look at a third party tool then, although in my mind I wouldn't want to do that.  The more native tools/functions I can use the better in my mind.